# Selenium python safari webdriver doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run the script, open safari, get the URL and after 10 sec it close and shows an error.
How fix it?

```
with webdriver.Safari as browser:
     browser.get('https://www.google.com/')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/main_1.py", line 55, in run
    browser.get(url)
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 449, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/main_1.py", line 125, in <module>
    run(login_user=login, password=password, url=url)
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/main_1.py", line 40, in run
    with webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/usr/bin/safaridriver') as browser:
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 300, in __exit__
    self.quit()
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/safari/webdriver.py", line 118, in quit
    super().quit()
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 562, in quit
    self.execute(Command.QUIT)
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/puzino/PycharmProjects/fiverr_usa/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Safari error:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000048
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000048
```

I tried to install the safari web driver

Comment: _When I run the script, open safari,_ Where is `script` ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `with webdriver.Safari as browser:
    browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
`